# get qr code via npm start to run react-native app on Expo emulator

Tags: react-native, expo

I've created an app with:

```
npm i -g create-react-native-app
create-react-native-app my-project
cd my-project
npm start
```

But when I run `npm start` no QR code is shown to cast via Expo app.
How can I get this QR Code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to create your app directly at the expo XDE,then get in your project folder and just run

```
expo start
```